# Import without changing the url with funnelweb

Tags: plone, plone-funnelweb

I have imported some pages from a site on the internet, to my plone site. The problem right now, is that when imported to plone, it changes the url, which results in plone not beeing able to locate the files. So before the import, here is an example of how one of the urls looks:

http://wiki.scandiatransplant.org/?What_Is_Scandiatransplant

And after the import, it looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/Scandiatransplant/wiki/index.html?What_Is_Scandiatransplant
```

Obviously this is a problem, as there is no option called index.html?
Is there a way to solve this? I am thinking maybe it could be fixed by adding a step in the pipeline.cfg file that tells not to change the url? This is just a guess though. And I haven't made a pipeline.cfg yet. The site: http://plone.org/products/funnelweb/#using-a-local-pipeline-configuration explains that one could make a pipeline.cfg file, but it doesn't tell where to place that file. Where should I place this file?

And finally... it can be expressed through regular expressions which files to ignore during the import, but I have not told funnelweb to ignore any files. Still it doesn't import the images, pdf file, xslt etc. Has anyone experienced this as well?

So, to summarize my questions.

1. Where should I place the pipeline.cfg file?
2. How do I make plone/funnel not to change the url, but keep the same url from the import?
3. How do I make funnelweb import the images and pdf files as well?

Answer (score 3):

1. You can put the pipeline.cfg file *anywhere*; you tell `funnelweb` where to find it from the command line:

   ```
   bin/funnelweb --pipeline=path/to/your/pipeline.cfg
   ```
2. This is more complex. Your target site is a Wiki, and the page names are part of the query string there. The `?What_Is_Scandiatransplant` needs to be used as the id of the new Plone page, and URLs used in other pages need to be rewritten to match.

   You can certainly do that in the pipeline, but is a little more complex than can easily be written up here. Follow the documentation for `funnelweb` (the `urltidy` component will help rewrite URLs), and feel free to ask specific questions about problems you encounter here on SO.
3. Check the logs and see what funnelweb already finds and uploads. You may have to adjust the webcrawler settings; this varies from site to site. Without more details about the site I can only give you this general hint.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, the answers do give me something to work on. Regarding question 3, I forgot to write that, after the import, it does look like the images have been uploaded, their real names and extensions (such as document.pdf) are there, but when I click on them, they are just empty. But I'll check the log when I get to the computer. Thanks. Something tells me that I'll be back with questions for answer 2 :-)

Comment: Hi again. I can't find any examples on how to express that you don't want the urls on the imported pages to be changed. Does anyone know any helful resource? This is what I used, it didn't help me on the specific problem: http://plone.org/products/funnelweb. Another problem I have, is that some of the imported pages require login. Are there rules for this, or will it work normally after the import? I can't test this yet, since I have the URL problem that prevents me. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, other than the provided documentation I have no further tips or help for you, short of going through the source code. I don't use funnelweb myself (I am the author of the underlying transmogrifier framework).